# Webmatrix: Add items to dynamic dropdown box from DB with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, razor, webmatrix

So i got a button to add more dropdown boxs done with jquery, here's the function that will create the new boxes

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var MaxSelects      = 7; //maximum input boxes allowed
var SelectsWrapper   = $("#SelectsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AdicionarButton       = $("#AdicionarFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = SelectsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AdicionarButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
    if(x <= MaxSelects) //max input box allowed
    {
        FieldCount++; //text box added increment
        //add input box
        $(SelectsWrapper).append('<div class="selectAplic"><select     name="aplicacaoPretendida" id="aplicacoes" class="col_11"></select><a class="removeclass"  href="#"><i class="icon-remove"></i></a></div>');
        x++; //text box increment
    }
return false;
});
```

However when i put my foreach inside nothing happens, The box is created but the content is empty.

```
       @foreach(var row in selectedData){
               foreach(var item in row.aplicacoes.ToString().Split(new [] {','})){
                          <option>@item</option>
               }
       }
```

This is my code working:

```
                            <div id="SelectsWrapper" class="col_8">
                                <div class="selectAplic">
                                    <select name="aplicacaoPretendida" id="aplicacoes" class="col_11" onchange='userExemplo()'>
                                         @foreach(var row in selectedData){
                                            foreach(var item in row.aplicacoes.ToString().Split(new [] {','})){
                                            <option>@item</option>
                                            }
                                        }
                                     </select>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

Now how can i add the foreach at mt jquery ?

Comment: You figure this out yet?

Comment: Not yet, i tried some things but can't figure it out